# Modules - import '/some/cool/module' without `from`

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I've recently seen the following:

```
import '/some/cool/module'
```

I was surprised that it didn't have `from` clause. It was written in TypeScript, but I can't find any information on this usage. It might be ES6 modules feature as well. What is it?

Comment: That just load the module, is the same as `require('/some/cool/module')`, that means it will execute whatever cool module have. e.g. console.log('Hello world');, when the import is executed it will print the message.

Comment: thanks, is it `es6` or `ts` feature? can you point to a relevant doc?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @cartant, where did you read about that _If something is not actually used, the import is entirely ignored and the somewhere module is not executed._?

Comment: @Maximus It's observed behaviour. That's the way TypeScript's compiler treats them (unused imports, that is) and I'm pretty sure that Rollup behaves in similar manner. Possibly Babel, too, but I'd have to check. Anyway, it's likely a module loader/bundler thing rather than a language spec.